# Extjs 3.4 load grid after load comboBox

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using Extjs 3.4. I have many `JsonStore` to load many `ComboBox`. I have an other JsonStore to load the data to populate an EditorGrid.
I want to load the `gridStore` after all `ComboBoxStores` have finished the loading process.
Is possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Each store emits events such as beforeload , load , that could be used to hookup any additional logic after the store has loaded.

I am not sure about you specific use-case but what you could do is , fire a custom event from each of the JSONstores on load( "load" event) and keep track of number of combobox stores loaded. Once all stores are loaded you could load the gridStore.